# How to clip image with another image in CGContext?

Tags: iphone, ios, cgcontext, masking, clipping

I want to get the following result with two images.

[image]

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To combine two images on an image view try this

```
UIImage *bottomImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bottom.png"]; //background image
UIImage *image       = [UIImage imageNamed:@"top.png"]; //foreground image
CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
// Use existing opacity as is
[bottomImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
// Apply supplied opacity if applicable
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.8];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Add `newImage` to UIImageView

Comment: Thanks for answering. But please look at the image exactly, the noise is only drawn onto the sole part.

Comment: Please follow the answer of @Prince after completing the code above, Mask the Image to get the desired solution

Answer (score 3):

After @Sumanth's code for combine two images you need to mask final image like [how-to-mask-an-image](https://www.innofied.com/implementing-image-masking-in-ios/) link